# Unable to construct this JSON object

Tags: java

I have the following Database structure

```
mysql> select * from categories limit 30;
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| category_id | T1          | T2              | T3    | T4   | T5   | T6   | T7   | T8   | T9   | T10  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|           1 | Popcorn     | Regular Pack    | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           1 | Popcorn     | Regular Pack    | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           1 | Popcorn     | Regular Pack    | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Popcorn     | Bucket          | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Popcorn     | Bucket          | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Popcorn     | Bucket          | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           3 | Popcorn     | Jumbo           | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           3 | Popcorn     | Jumbo           | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           4 | Popcorn     | Tub             | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           4 | Popcorn     | Tub             | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           5 | Popcorn     | Combo Cool Bite | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           6 | Popcorn     | Combo Relish    | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |


|           7 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Apple      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           8 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Orange     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           8 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Orange     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           9 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Lemon      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           9 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Lemon      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          10 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Clear      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          10 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Clear      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          11 | Soft Drinks | Tin             | Apple      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          11 | Soft Drinks | Tin             | Apple      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          12 | Soft Drinks | Tin             | Lean Apple | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          12 | Soft Drinks | Tin             | Lean Apple | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I am trying to create a Json structure for the above in this format.

For example

The following two arrays . (pseudo code )

```
PopCorn :[Regular Pack, Bucket ,Jumbo,Tub,Combo Cool Bite,Combo Relish]

Soft Drinks:[Fountain,Tin]
```

I am trying to get all the distinct elements of T1 and combine distinct elements of T2

I have been able to do it in this way:

```
JSONArray T1array=new JSONArray();
JSONArray T2array=new JSONArray();

 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String T1 = rs.getString("T1");
            String T2 = rs.getString("T2");
            if(!tempvariable.equals(T1))
            {
                T1array.put(T1);
            //  T2array.put(T2);
            }
             tempvariable = T1;

        }
```

Please tell me how I can map T2 with T1

Comment: I did not understand your question clearly,can you please make it more clear

Comment: Create JSON as PopCorn :[Regular Pack, Bucket ,Jumbo,Tub,Combo Cool Bite,Combo Relish]  and Soft Drinks:[Fountain,Tin] as they both are related to each other know .

Comment: How about using a map of sets? You could use T1 as key, and have distinct values of T2 as members of the contained set.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be

```
Map<String, Set<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
    String T1 = rs.getString("T1");
    String T2 = rs.getString("T2");
    Set<String> t2 = tempMap.get(T1);
    if(t2 == null)
    {
       t2 = new HashSet<String>();
       tempMap.put(T1, t2);
    }
    t2.add(T2);
}
```

Afterwards you have all distinct T1 as keys in the tempMap, and in the Set value all the distinct T2 for them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution , i cannot use your solution as some elements can have T3 as another level and upto T10 .

Comment: Ya i thought that if i can get upto 1 level , then i can get upto n level . so i didn't mention ,sorry if it is irrelevant .